# Determinant of a nxn symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I tried this problem but I failed.
It is a symmetric matrix, it should be orthogonal diagonalizable.
If I can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix, then i can calculate it easily.
The answer should be the product of their eigenvalues.

However I am unable to find the eigenvalues since it is a nxn matrix.
(I used online calculator to checke, the eigenvalues should be $(n-1)$ times $(x-a)$ and $1 \times [x-(n-1)a]$
May anyone give me any tips on this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Finding eigenvalues/eigenvectors is far harder than finding the determinant. Usually you want to do some sort of inductive/recursive argument with matrices like this.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).